# First order non linear Ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the first order differential equation
 $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y)= -16t^{3}y^{2}$, with the inital condition $y(0)=1$
 Estimate the lipschitz derivative for the differential equation by substituting the exact solution into $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

I found the exact solution by using the separable of variable and doing integration
 which is $y(t)= (4t^4 + 1)^{-1}$
 And also I found the $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -32yt^3$
 The question ask about by substituting the exact solution into $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ to estimate the lipschitz derivative. I don't know how to substitute.
 Does anyone knows about lipschitz derivative?

Help me Please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of  "Lipschitz derivative" as standard terminology in mathematics.  However, in the existence and uniqueness theorem for differential equations one of the hypotheses is a Lipschitz condition $|f(t,y) - f(t,z)| \le L |y - z|$, 
and I believe the question is referring to this $L$.  For differentiable functions, it's simply a bound on the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial y$.

"Substitute" means plug in the value of $y(t)$ that you found into the 
expression for the partial derivative: $-32 y t^3 = -32 (4 t^4 + 1)^{-1} t^3$.

Comment: After i got this equation: -32yt^3 =-32(4t^4 +1)^-1 t^3 ,what i have to do next

Comment: You are asked to estimate this.  On what interval?  Remember from calculus how to maximize or minimize a function.

Comment: Now i want to plot this partial derivative ∂f/∂y = |-32 (4t^4 +1)^-1 t^3| against t using fortran to generate a file or something for the matlab to plot the graph. Does fortran plot the graph?
Help me please

Comment: Why in the world would you want to use fortran for that?  Matlab can plot it just fine.

Comment: because i have to write program in fortran